# Android - abstract class that extends activity or TabActivity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have created an abstract class which extends the Activity Class.

I want to extend it in an activity which extends TabActivity Class, how can I achieve that?

Get the TabActivity and abstract class Functionality at the same time.

I do realize that multiple inheritance is not possible in Java, but can I avoid extending TabActivity Class and still use getTabHost()?

10x :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this with this design. If your abstract class extending SomeOtherActivityClass and new Class need to extended SomeotherActivityClass (through inheritence) and TabActivityClass, that may confuse dalvik to choose which activity at runtime and it doesn't make sense. You may need to reconsider your design.

Answer (score 0):

yes sure, you can use. By using following snippet:

TabHost host=(TabHost)findViewById(id of tabhost);

Answer (score 0):

It's better way to create another class that extends Application class. Or use singleton pattern and create class with all functionality that you're need.